# Laptop usb not working?

Tags: laptop, usb, mouse, hardware-failure

I think there is something wrong with my laptop usb ports, but I am not 100% sure. I have tried to connect multiple mouses to my laptop but they are working like 50/50. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I tried to connect it to my computer and it just worked perfectly. When I use my laptop at work, my mouse never suddenly stops working. I really cant make a connection of what is going wrong. When it suddenly doesn't work I get a message with: `USB device not recognized` Now I have 3 usb ports.

1: When I connect a mouse to it, it will light up and immediatly stop. Then it gives me the message: `USB device not recognized`

2/3: When I connect a mouse to it, it will light up and quickly go on/off again and the mouse wont work. When I position the cable of the mouse differently, It will work(can be for hours) then all of the sudden it could just stop working again.

What is going wrong?

The above is with one mouse atm.

I tried it with another mouse and the mouse light would just keep being on but it wont work. I took the mouse (which light just goes on an off again) to work and it worked perfectly for the whole day in all the usb ports.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing there's a bad connection that makes any usb device plugged in lose power when it's not in the right position. Have the ports been over-used? Is this an old laptop?
If I'm right, a solution might be to buy an express-card (or pcmcia, depending on how old the laptop is) usb hub and use that.

Found some on ebay:

- [ExpressCard 34mm](http://www.ebay.com/itm/181127357706)
- [ExpressCard 54mm](http://www.ebay.com/itm/190801419821)

I've used the 54 mm one for a couple of years now, and it works perfectly. Hope I helped.

Comment: not an old laptop. + other deevices on the usb is working perfectly.

Comment: Try with another mouse. If that one behaves properly then the problem is likely in the mouse. (And if it also fails you can rules that out).

Comment: There are also things like the tooth pick trick to try and repair USB connections.

Comment: Then I agree with @Hennes .  If other devices work perfectly, but that mouse gives you occasional problems, it's the mouse.

Comment: @DaJF I;ve already tried other mouses

Comment: I may be power issue then, USB is delivers very little power unless a device asks for more. If your mouse needs more, there may be a problem with this negotiation for more power, causing it to fail. I'm unsure whether re-installing the drivers for your chipset will have any effect, but that never hurts. (check "Device Manager" > "Universal Serial Bus controllers") If nothing helps, what I originally suggested (expresscard from ebay) might be your only option.

Comment: @DaJF I uninstalled the drivers and I restarted it. Now 2 of my usb ports aren't working anymore...

Comment: That points to a serious problem.. So two don't work anymore, but the third one does? Could you maybe give a bit more info? Like laptop modelnr, chipset, os, and anything else you think might be relevant.

Comment: @DaJF The third one does, but it still doesn't receive the mouse now. Maybe we could go into chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12111/discussion-between-loko-and-dajf)